# react router apache config in sub directory

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router, subdirectory

i have a react app that i've deployed on subdirectory of a site,
the subdirectory is something like this `www.example.com/iapp`, i've also configed my `package.json` and Router to that subdirectory like below.
in my package.json :

```
 "homepage": "example.com/iapp",
```

and in my router i've added a basename like below

```
 <Router basename={'/iapp'}>
</Router>
```

everything works fine and all, but the routing is off, when i reload page anywhere but this url:
`example.com/iapp` nothing loads, and a blank page shows up.
i know this has something to do with `htaccess` and apache config for react router, but i can't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So yeah, I found a way to do this, and it was pretty easy, so what you're gonna do is create an `.htaccess` file in your subdirectory, for me the name of that subdirectory was `iapp` and then add the below config to it, and that's it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /iapp
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /iapp/index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```